# Install python on an embedded device

Tags: linux, package-management, python, embedded, arm

I'm working on an embedded device already customized. Here some details:

```
# uname -a
Linux DX-4400 3.10.31-ltsi-05172-g28bac3e-dirty #12 SMP Tue Jan 23 17:14:13 EST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I have root access, rw /, Internet connection, but neither a package manager nor build essentials. I would avoid - if possible - to prepare a cross-build environment.

I wonder if with this information (or with others I can retrieve) there's a way to install Python's binaries to the system - or even a package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, but note Linux is not Gnu/Linux. When people say Linux, sometimes they mean the Gnu/Linux system, sometimes they mean the Kernel call Linux. The word Linux in the above output, is the name of the kernel, it does not imply that you are running a Gnu/Linux system.

If you are prepared to put in the effort, then you can probably build python and all of the dependencies.

If you look-up the device on the web, you may find what others have done. Without more detail, it will be impossible to give more help.

Comment: I understand but I don't know what details might be useful. Please tell me and I will update my question! I meant, knowing the architecture (armv7l) is not enough to search for Python's binaries?

Comment: " it does not imply that you are running a Gnu/Linux system" - the last part of the output states `armv7l GNU/Linux` still not enough to be sure?

Comment: Oh I missed that, but still as you say “can not be sure” how much Gnu is on there.